# Referencing of class variables (static) within managed beans

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2.2

I have a class (static) variable in a managed bean. Is it legal to reference this class variable from within another managed bean like so:

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class FooBean {
    private Context ctx;
    public static DataSource ds;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        ctx = new InitialContext();
        ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/foobar");
    }        
}

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class BarBean {
    public void foobar() {
        // Is that legal and save?
        Connection conn = FooBean.ds.getConnection();
    }
}
```

Should I use dependency injection instead?

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class BarBean {
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{fooBean}")
    private FooBean fooBean;

    public void foobar() {
        Connection conn = fooBean.get_ds().getConnection();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would work because `FooBean` has been already loaded before the `BarBean` calls `FooBean.ds.getConnection();` which by their scope it won't be an issue.

It doesn't look right to call `FooBean.ds.getConnection();` knowing that the first bean will be loaded because is `@ApplicationScoped` but it would work as soon as there is no multithreading or proper management on your Datasource.

The I would not be sure how it would get Garbage Collected.

I would use CDI `@Inject` (over old `@ ManagedProperty` - still works like charm though) or Spring `@Autowired` to inject other resources instances, beans, EJB, services, etc.

So my answer is use the power of Dependency Injection over static class member.